# What is the best way to create a Dev & Prod environment in 1 environment

Tags: 2013, development, web-application, production

We need to make changes to the design of the site. Unfortunately the client doesn't have the luxury of a **Dev** environment. What would be the best way to allow the **Devs** to perform work on a *backup* of the existing WebApp while in the same environment of the **Prod**?

Answer (score 0):

We have achieved this by running a backup of the Site Collection and restoring it to a newly created Web Application. All is working as intended and the Dev's can do their work.

Comment: As long as everyone is aware of the caveats, running two web applications should be sufficient.  However, if your team is building farm solutions, then you need farm level isolation.